# Writing a XORshift128 pRNG with Signed Integers

Tags: random, int, bit-manipulation

In the programming language I'm using (GML) all numbers are confined to signed int64s (or float64s). How would I implement this XORshift128+ pRNG (currently coded in C) with that sort of limitation? I would also accept a higher bit count if the programming would be easier.

```
static uint32_t s[4] = { 0x8764000b, 0xf542d2d3, 0x6fa035c3, 0x77f2db5b };

static inline uint32_t rotl(const uint32_t x, int k) {
    return (x << k) | (x >> (32 - k));
}

uint32_t next(void) {
    const uint32_t result = s[0] + s[3];

    const uint32_t t = s[1] << 9;

    s[2] ^= s[0];
    s[3] ^= s[1];
    s[1] ^= s[2];
    s[0] ^= s[3];

    s[2] ^= t;

    s[3] = rotl(s[3], 11);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your C code uses unsigned int32 values, which will fit inside your signed int64s without any difficulty. Just make sure you constrain the output of `rotl()` and the results of the first 2 lines of `next()` to 32 bits (i.e., `return ((x << k) | (x >> (32 - k))) & 0xffffffff;`, `result = (s[0] + s[3]) & 0xffffffff;` and `t = (s[1] << 9) & 0xffffffff;`).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about the `& 0xffffffff` option. I was stuffing the output into uint32 buffers to constrain them.

Wouldn't rotl not work properly because I wouldn't actually be rotating the bits around, just shifting them into the 64 bit space? @r3mainer

Comment: That's all the `rotl()` function does; It just shifts bits around.

Comment: Maybe you could also help me with this?
`uint64_t x = 0, w = 0, s = 0xb5ad4eceda1ce2a9;inline static uint32_t msws() {x *= x; x += (w += s); return x = (x>>32) | (x<<32);}`
@r3mainer

Comment: Well, since that function is supposed to return a uint32_t value, I would just replace the last line with `return (x = (x>>32) | (x<<32)) & 0xffffffff;`. I don't think anything else needs to be changed. However, [this isn't a very good random number generator.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method)